# data classes in Kotlin multiplatform programming

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I`m new at kotlin and want to build a multiplatform application.
For the common part I want to use data classes that contains platform specific functions.

Is it possible to use the kotlin data class in a platform specific declaration?

something like

```
expect data class Foo(val bar: String)
```

best regards

Comment: What do you expect the difference to be between `expect data class` and `expect class`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Kotlin's docs on [Platform Specific Declarations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/platform-specific-declarations.html):

> Expected declarations never contain any implementation code.

Since data classes generate implementations they can't be used in `expect` declarations. The `actual` implementation can be a data class since it does not change the semantics of the declared class.

Comment: Maybe a `expected fun Foo.platformSpecificFun(...)` can be used to enrich the data class.

Comment: Oh yes, the constructor... Thank you! To declare only the platform specific class as a data class works for me

Answer (score 1):

Here's my working example:

EXPECT (commonMain)

```
@Serializable
expect class Person {
    val id: Long
    val name: String
}
```

ACTUAL (jvmMain)

```
@Serializable
actual data class Person (
    @SerialName("_id")
    actual val id: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()
    actual val name: String
)
```

ACTUAL (jsMain)

```
@Serializable
actual data class Person (
    @SerialName("_id")
    actual val id: Long = Date.now().toLong()
    actual val name: String
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
expect class Some {}

actual data class Some(val test: UUID)
```